# Scroll Indicator

Tags: javascript, scroll, calculation

This code makes [***this***](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp) scroll indicator.

Can you please help me figure out how do the variable `scrolled` is calculated here?

Please explain why `clientHeight` is subtracted from `scrollHeight` and `winScroll` variable  is divided by `height` then multiplied by `100`?

---

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Indicator</h2>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Scroll Down to See The Effect</h3>
  <p>100 text line</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clientHeight` returns the height of the enclosing div. [clientHeight reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)

The `scrollHeight` read-only property is a measurement of the height of an element's content, including content not visible on the screen due to overflow. [scrollHeight reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)

An element's `scrollTop` value is a measurement of the distance from the element's top to its topmost visible content. [scrollTop reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

Subtracting the `clientHeight` form `scrollHeight` provides the maximum `scrollTop` value that can be obtained. When the scroll reaches the bottom of the page, the `scrollTop` value becomes equal to that of the `height`.

The division with `height` and multiplication with 100 is to obtain the percent of scroll.

Comment: One more thing, why or ( || ) is used between document.body and document.documentElement.